# Dropdown is hidden when used with malihu scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, semantic-ui

I'm using The malihu scrollbar in combination with a semantic ui dropdown. I expected the dropdown to overflow the scrollbar so all content would be shown. Instead it hides the dropdown under the scrollbar so the items are invisible.

The html that I use for the dropdown is from Semantic UI:

```
<div class="ui compact menu">
<div class="ui simple dropdown item">
  Dropdown
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Choice 1</div>
    <div class="item">Choice 2</div>
    <div class="item">Choice 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Try giving `div.menu` the CSS `overflow: visible !important;`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyone else have this issue? I cant seem to get around it myself